# CodeIgniter issue with database library

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am trying to build a custom library of a Shopping Cart. I had some issues with loading the database library into the Cart class but I solved that with using:

```
$CI =$ get_instance();
$CI->load->database();
```

But now whenever I want to use the database library it gives me the error: "Trying to get property of non-object" on this line:

```
$this->CI->db->insert("carts", $data);
```

I should mention that I declared the $CI variable at the top of my class like this:

```
var $CI;
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$CI` is a class variable, as you say it is, then you'll need to use

```
$this->CI =& get_instance();
$this->CI->load->database();
```

instead of

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->database();
```

initialize `$this->CI` in constructor to make available in every methods.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly!